# Is allowed duplicate project name on github under different user/organization name?

Tags: github

I'm trying to create my repo on github, open source, but I found the project name was already used by another user for his project, may I use the same name? Any brand issue?

Comment: Afaik you can have a project of the same name as long as your username (organization name) is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the same name as another project, you may promote confusion especially if they are within the same ecosystem (language/framework) as the other.

I'd recommend a different name, unless the mentioned don't apply.

Comment: So the brand conflict, if there were, is another separate question, right?